# Como minimizar uma aplicação em C#?

Tags: c#, windows

Como faço para minimizar ou fechar (para a bandeja) qualquer aplicação pelo C#? Estou tentando minimizar o TeamSpeak para a bandeja do sistema.

Comment: Onde está o código?

Comment: http://www.jasinskionline.com/windowsapi/ref/s/showwindow.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Terá que buscar a aplicação pelo nome ou ID via [**`Process.GetProcesses`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses(v=vs.110).aspx), ou [**`Process.GetProcessByName`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname(v=vs.110).aspx), ou [**`Process.GetProcessById`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyid(v=vs.110).aspx)

Um detalhe importante, não tem como minimizar para o *SystemTray*, isso depende da aplicação, geralmente aplicações minimizadas que suportam o *SystemTray* nativamente podem ser configuradas para usar *SystemTray* no momento em que minimizam, mas nem toda aplicação externa vai ter esse capacidade, ainda sim pode experimentar minimizar.

Criei um exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...

public class HandleApp
{
    //Enumera os tipos para usar com o switch (o 1,2,3 são da API do user32)
    public enum Actions { Normal = 1, Minimize = 2, Maximize = 3 };

    //Importa o user32.dll para poder usar as APIs nativas
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    //Busca um aplicativo pelo nome
    public static IntPtr FindWindow(string title)
    {
        Process[] pros = Process.GetProcessesByName(title);

        if (pros.Length == 0)
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        return pros[0].MainWindowHandle;
    }

    //Dispara a ação desejada, só tem 3 opções no exemplo
    public static void Action(string name, Actions act)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(name);

        if (!hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
            ShowWindowAsync(hWnd, (int) act);
    }
}
```

### Exemplos de uso

Busca um aplicativo pelo nome e se for encontrada minimiza ele:

```
HandleApp.Action("notepad", HandleApp.Actions.Minimize);
```

Busca um aplicativo pelo nome e se for encontrada maximiza ele:

```
HandleApp.Action("notepad", HandleApp.Actions.Maximize);
```

Busca um aplicativo pelo nome e se for encontrado deixa o tamanho normal (padrão):

```
HandleApp.Action("notepad", HandleApp.Actions.Normal);
```

---

### Extra

Você pode adicionar mais funcionalidades para o:

```
public enum Actions { Normal = 1, Minimize = 2, Maximize = 3 };
```

Os números de cada `enum` devem seguir estes [*ShowWindow function* <sup>(en)</sup>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx), no caso usei 1, 2 e 3 que seriam `SW_SHOWNORMAL`, `SW_SHOWMINIMIZED` e `SW_SHOWMAXIMED` respectivamente, segue a lista:

| Enum | Valor | Descrição |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `SW_HIDE` | 0 | Esconde a janela e ativa outra janela. |
| `SW_SHOWNORMAL` | 1 | Ativa e exibe uma janela. Se a janela for minimizada ou maximizada, o sistema restaura seu tamanho e posição original. Um aplicativo deve especificar esse sinalizador ao exibir a janela pela primeira vez. |
| `SW_SHOWMINIMIZED` | 2 | Ativa a janela e a exibe como uma janela minimizada. |
| `SW_SHOWMAXIMED` | 3 | Ativa a janela e a exibe como uma janela maximizada. |
| `SW_MAXIMIZE` | 3 | Maximiza a janela especificada. |
| `SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE` | 4 | Exibe uma janela em seu tamanho e posição mais recentes. Esse valor é semelhante ao `SW_SHOWNORMAL` , exceto que a janela não ficará ativada. |
| `SW_SHOW` | 5 | Ativa a janela e a exibe em seu tamanho e posição atuais. |
| `SW_MINIMIZE` | 6 | Minimiza a janela especificada e ativa a próxima janela de nível superior na ordem Z. |
| `SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE` | 7 | Exibe a janela como uma janela minimizada. Esse valor é semelhante ao SW_SHOWMINIMIZED, exceto que a janela não não fica ativada. |
| `SW_SHOWNA` | 8 | Exibe a janela em seu tamanho e posição atuais. Esse valor é semelhante ao `SW_SHOW` , exceto que a janela não está ativada. |
| `SW_RESTORE` | 9 | Ativa e exibe a janela. Se a janela for minimizada ou maximizada, o sistema restaura seu tamanho e posição original. Um aplicativo deve especificar esse sinalizador ao restaurar uma janela minimizada. |
| `SW_SHOWDEFAULT` | 10 | Define o estado de exibição com base no valor SW_ especificado na estrutura STARTUPINFO passada para a função CreateProcess pelo programa que iniciou o aplicativo. |
| `SW_FORCEMINIMIZE` | 11 | Minimiza uma janela, mesmo que o segmento que possui a janela não está respondendo. Esta bandeira só deve ser usada ao minimizar as janelas de um segmento diferente. |

Comment: Obrigado! Achei no SO en mas não tinha entendido, agora temos também no SO pt.

Comment: Você fez essa tabela? Haja paciência.

Comment: @CypherPotato além de fazer a tabela os itens estavam desordenados, foi um pouco trabalhoso, mas achei que ficaria interessante para que quisesse implementar mais funcionalidades ;)

Answer (score -3):

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Process[] pros = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");
  IntPtr hnd = pros[0].MainWindowHandle; 
  ShowWindow(hnd,2);
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow); // função externa
```

Comment: Uma pequena explicação ajudaria a compreender a sua resposta.